# Finding the center of mass for a centroid without a convenient symmetry axis

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Find the centroid of the lamina described in polar coordinates as 
$\left \{ \strut \left ( x,y \right )~|~0\leq r\leq 4 \cos\left ( \theta \right ),0\leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{3} \right \}$

Having a bit of a problem with this problem. Any hints to set me in the right direction would be ideal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $D=\{(r,\theta)\;|\; 0\le \theta \le \pi/3,  0 \le r  \le 4 \cos \theta  \}$, and $\rho(x,y)$ the surface density of the solid.

The coordinates of the centroid are given by 
$$
\hat{x}=\frac{\iint_D x \rho(x,y) dA}{\iint_D  \rho(x,y) dA}\\
\hat{y}=\frac{\iint_D y \rho(x,y) dA}{\iint_D  \rho(x,y) dA}
$$

You just need to replace $x$ by $r\cos{\theta}$, $y$ by $r\sin{\theta}$, and $dA$ by $rdrd\theta$.

Comment: What??  This is a [b]circle[/b]!   The "centroid" is the center of the circle.

Comment: No, it depends on the density. Plus its not a circle. For a circle we would need $\theta$ to range from $0$ to $\pi/2$.

Comment: The original post asked for the "centroid", not the "center of mass".  The "centroid" of a figure is a geometric concept that has nothing to do with "density" or mass.

Comment: Actually, if the density is uniform, than the center of mass and centroid have the same coordinates. So there is a link between the two concepts, and if the density is constant than the formulas above will give you the right answer.